# Migrating from Flyspray to Redmine

Tags: migration, redmine

I am wondering if anyone knows how to move from Flyspray to Redmine? I haven't been able to find any documentation at all so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of searching on Google turned up [flyspray2redmine](https://sources.beeznest.net/public/flyspray2redmine). It looks like this worked for somebody at some time, but no guarantees.

Comment: Oh nice, that does do a migration even if it is a bit older. Thanks!